# horizontal scrolling/swiping effect on desktop with JqueryUI draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, horizontal-scrolling

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3mh2b7rk/76/)

Is it possible to use `draggable` to simulate horizontal scrolling on desktop? In the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/3mh2b7rk/76/), the child elements in `.child` are pretty long. Instead of going down to the bottom to use the horizontal scrollbar, I want to achieve the same effect by dragging/swiping `.child`. I have tried

```
jQuery(".child").draggable({ 
    cursor: "move", 
    containment: ".parent"
});
```

But it doesn't really move.

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8e40ed586c618389587885b8c3fb16c4?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"/>
      <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8e40ed586c618389587885b8c3fb16c4?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"/>
      <span>random element</span>
      <span>random txt</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made something like that with basic jQuery not too long ago : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXRZYO?editors=001. Separates swipes from clicks too and will revert to momentum scrolling on mobile if possible. It's responsive and will keep the currently centered item in place when resizing.

Comment: @Shikkediel , it works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: That's great! You're welcome of course. :-)